# Proving a congrent modular

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I show that $3^{1974}+5^{1974}\equiv 0 \pmod {13}$? I have tried feeding the values onto a calculator but they are so big to be computed. What is the best approach?

Comment: Hint:  $3^3\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$, hence $3^{3k}\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$ for any $k$.  Can you work out powers of $5$?

Comment: Will it be 5^K=13(mod 0)?

Comment: do you understand the meaning of mod ?

Comment: There can't be any $k$ with $5^k\equiv 13 \pmod {13}$.  Can you work out $5^2, 5^3,5^4, 5^5,\cdots$?  (all $\pmod {13}$ of course). You need to find a pattern...so you can quickly compute, say,  $5^{100}\pmod {13}$ instantly.

Comment: Who said $9\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$?

Comment: You can't figure out why $27\equiv 1\pmod {13}$?  Go back to the definition, work a lot of examples.

Comment: Now am getting it.

Answer (score 0):

By Fermat's Little Theorem,
$$3^{12}\equiv5^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$$
and since $1968$ is divisible by $12$,

$$3^{1974}+5^{1974}\equiv 3^6+5^6\pmod{13}$$

etc.

Comment: I fully appreciate that, but how will this ,lead to the 0 mod13 part?

Answer (score 0):

since Fermat's little theorem, implies $3^{12}\equiv5^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ we have: 
$$
3^{1974}+5^{1974}=3^{12*164+6}+5^{12*164+6}=(3^{12})^{164}3^6+(5^{12})^{164}5^6\equiv 3^6+5^6 \pmod{13}
$$ 
Now, you can easily see that:
$$3^3=27\equiv 1\pmod{13}\Rightarrow 3^6=1\pmod{13}$$
and:
$$5^2=25\equiv -1\pmod{13}\Rightarrow5^6=-1\pmod{13}$$
thus, summing the above:
$$
3^{1974}+5^{1974}\equiv 3^6+5^6 \equiv 1-1 =0 \pmod{13}
$$